# FFmpeg の Android での利用方法について

Tags: android, ffmpeg

Android 5.0以上を対象に動画編集アプリを開発しようとしていまして、そのために以下の環境にてAndroidへのFFMPEG組み込みを行おうとしております。

- Android Studio 2.3.3
- FFmpeg 3.3.2

[ffmpegをAndroid用にビルドする方法](http://nextat.co.jp/staff/archives/97)

上記サイトを参考にFFmpegのコンパイルやAndroid.mkを作成してのAndroidプロジェクトへの組み込みを行っていますが、うまくいっておりません。

色々なサイトを調べているのですが、環境のEclipseとAndroid Studioの違い、またAndroid Studioのバージョンによるビルドに関する仕様の違いなどがあるらしく、基になる環境が異なる情報が入り混じってしまい、正しい形というのが分かっていない状況です。

最初に記載した

- Android 5.0
- Android Studio 2.3.3
- FFmpeg 3.3.2

上記条件でFFmpegの組み込みを行う場合、どういった作業が必要なのか、またどういった手順なのか、ご存知の方がいましたらご教授いただけますでしょうか。

**発生しているエラー**

```
ffmpeg.c:11: error: undefined reference to 'avcodec_version'  
clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**Cのソースコード**

```
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>

jstring Java_<パッケージ名>_TopActivity_stringFromJNI( JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz ) {
    //avcodec_register_all();
    int test = avcodec_version();

    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello JNI !");
}
```

Comment: http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android/ が参考になるかと思います。バイナリ配布もされているので、それで十分ならそちらを。

Comment: 情報をご教示いただきありがとうございます。  ご教示いただいたサイトを参考にしながら組み込み用のファイルを作成するところまでは行うことができました。

Comment: ただ作成したファイルをAndroidStudioに組み込み、Cのコードからヘッダーファイルを参照させようとすると下記のエラーが出てndk-buildを完了することができませんでした。

Comment: "undefined reference to～"はリンクエラーを示しています。FFmpegビルドで生成される`libavcodec.so`（のような名前の）ファイルをリンク指定する必要があります。

Comment: .soではなく、.aファイルが生成されており、それをsrc/main/jni/lib配下に配置し、Android.mkのLOCAL_SRC_FILESに各ライブラリファイルを記載しております。　これはリンク指定とは異なるものなのでしょうか?

Comment: 拡張子.aであれば静的ライブラリになりますから、`LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES`で指定する必要があります。see https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/android_mk.html

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/84227

Comment: 返答が遅くなりすみません。マルチポストのマナーを知らずに投稿しておりました。またひとまずある段階まで自己解決することができました。ご協力いただきありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android/
上記のサイトを参考にしつつ、ひとまずライブラリを利用できる状態までにはすることができました。

./android-ndk-r14b
./WritingMinds-ffmpeg-android-8809612
このようなに各フォルダを配置し、以下のように各ファイルの内容を編集しました。

■./WritingMinds-ffmpeg-android-8809612/android_build.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

. settings.sh

BASEDIR=$(pwd)
TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX=${BASEDIR}/toolchain-android
# Applying required patches
patch  -p0 -N --dry-run --silent -f fontconfig/src/fcxml.c < android_donot_use_lconv.patch 1>/dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  patch -p0 -f fontconfig/src/fcxml.c < android_donot_use_lconv.patch
fi

for i in "${SUPPORTED_ARCHITECTURES[@]}"
do
  rm -rf ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}
  # $1 = architecture
  # $2 = base directory
  # $3 = pass 1 if you want to export default compiler environment variables
  ./libpng_build.sh $i $BASEDIR 1 || exit 1
  ./expat_build.sh $i $BASEDIR 1 || exit 1
  ./ffmpeg_build.sh $i $BASEDIR 0 || exit 1
done

rm -rf ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}
```

■./WritingMinds-ffmpeg-android-8809612/abi_settings.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

. settings.sh

BASEDIR=$2

case $1 in
  armeabi-v7a)
    NDK_ABI='arm'
    NDK_TOOLCHAIN_ABI='arm-linux-androideabi'
    NDK_CROSS_PREFIX="${NDK_TOOLCHAIN_ABI}"
  ;;
  x86)
    NDK_ABI='x86'
    NDK_TOOLCHAIN_ABI='x86'
    NDK_CROSS_PREFIX="i686-linux-android"
    CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -march=i686"
  ;;
esac

TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX=${BASEDIR}/toolchain-android
if [ ! -d "$TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX" ]; then
  ${ANDROID_NDK_ROOT_PATH}/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh --toolchain=${NDK_TOOLCHAIN_ABI}-${NDK_TOOLCHAIN_ABI_VERSION} --platform=android-${ANDROID_API_VERSION} --install-dir=${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}
fi
CROSS_PREFIX=${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}/bin/${NDK_CROSS_PREFIX}-
NDK_SYSROOT=${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}/sysroot

export PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR="${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}/lib/pkgconfig"

if [ $3 == 1 ]; then
  export CC="${CROSS_PREFIX}gcc --sysroot=${NDK_SYSROOT}"
  export LD="${CROSS_PREFIX}ld"
  export RANLIB="${CROSS_PREFIX}ranlib"
  export STRIP="${CROSS_PREFIX}strip"
  export READELF="${CROSS_PREFIX}readelf"
  export OBJDUMP="${CROSS_PREFIX}objdump"
  export ADDR2LINE="${CROSS_PREFIX}addr2line"
  export AR="${CROSS_PREFIX}ar"
  export AS="${CROSS_PREFIX}as"
  export CXX="${CROSS_PREFIX}g++"
  export OBJCOPY="${CROSS_PREFIX}objcopy"
  export ELFEDIT="${CROSS_PREFIX}elfedit"
  export CPP="${CROSS_PREFIX}cpp"
  export DWP="${CROSS_PREFIX}dwp"
  export GCONV="${CROSS_PREFIX}gconv"
  export GDP="${CROSS_PREFIX}gdb"
  export GPROF="${CROSS_PREFIX}gprof"
  export NM="${CROSS_PREFIX}nm"
  export SIZE="${CROSS_PREFIX}size"
  export STRINGS="${CROSS_PREFIX}strings"
fi
```

■./WritingMinds-ffmpeg-android-8809612/settings.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

SUPPORTED_ARCHITECTURES=(armeabi-v7a x86)
ANDROID_NDK_ROOT_PATH=${ANDROID_NDK}
if [[ -z "$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT_PATH" ]]; then
  echo "You need to set ANDROID_NDK environment variable, please check instructions"
  exit
fi
ANDROID_API_VERSION=21
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_ABI_VERSION=4.9

NUMBER_OF_CORES=$(nproc)
HOST_UNAME=$(uname -m)
TARGET_OS=linux

CFLAGS='-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all'
LDFLAGS='-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie'

FFMPEG_PKG_CONFIG="$(pwd)/ffmpeg-pkg-config"
```

その後、環境変数として以下を登録
　ANDROID_NDK=/<～ルートからのパス～>/android-ndk-r14b

/WritingMinds-ffmpeg-android-8809612に移動してandroid_build.shを実行
　./android_build.sh

以下のフォルダ配下に.soのライブラリファイルが作成される
　./WritingMinds-ffmpeg-android-8809612/build

この.soファイルを使ってFFmpegの機能をAndroid側で利用できることは最低限確認することができました。
ここからどういった形で機能を実装していくかという問題が新たに出てはいますが、ライブラリを作成するという点ではひとまず上手くいきました。
今後の実装方法についてはまた別途質問の方を投げさせていただこうと思います。